# Com port, Аналог функции ReadFile()

Tags: visual-c++, c++

В стандартной библиотеке есть функция

> ReadFile(hCom,  // handle of file to read
>     inputData,             // handle of file to read
>    sizeBuffer,              // number of bytes to read
>     &length, 
>     // pointer to number of bytes read
>     NULL)          // pointer to structure for data

Но у этой функции есть 1 большой недостаток-мы должны знать точный объем информации, которое мы должны принять. Если же сказать функции читать информацию, а информации не будет, то функция будет ждать эту информацию очень долго. 
В моем случае это общение с устройством через ком порт.

Может вы знаете другую функцию, которая читает ком порт только в том случае если есть что читать. А если нет, то идет дальше по программе?

Comment: А если msdn почитать? На тему асинхронных операций...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошая статья на тему работы с `COM`, используя `WINAPI`: [Работа с COM-портом с помощью потоков](http://www.piclist.ru/S-COM-THREAD-RUS/S-COM-THREAD-RUS.html).